# SSC cgl 2016 tier 1 asked question

Tags: trigonometry

> [Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgff8.jpg)
>   If $\cot\alpha = 4$,
>   find the value of 
>   $$\frac{5\sin\alpha + 3 \cos\alpha}{5\sin\alpha - 3 \cos\alpha}$$

Options available to me were

> $(1)~1/9$
>   $(2)~1/3$
>   $(3)~3$
>   $(4)~9$

Comment: there were only 4 options as provided above in exam

Comment: You need to write atleast what you tried and where you got stuck in the problem.It will help us to answer.Please follow this in future.Anyway welcome to MSE.

Comment: Apparently, "none of the above"

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot Q = \frac{\cos Q}{\sin Q}$$

Then you can divide your terms by $\sin Q$ and get

$$\frac{\sin Q\left(5 + 3\cot Q\right)}{\sin Q(5 - 3\cot Q)} = \frac{5 + 12}{5 - 12} = \frac{17}{-7} = -\frac{17}{7}$$

Comment: _None_ of the given answers match yours.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel. Correct ... but this is the solution

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know, right? Sometimes question-setters fail to check their own questions...

Answer (score 0):

Divide the expression by $\sin Q$.
You have $(5+3 \cot Q)/(5-3 \cot Q)$.